# Liquid Rainbow Script Color change

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change the color of this liquid rainbow script to shades of purple only An I cant seem to figure it out.

```
Script in in Code pen editor.

[Code Pen Editor][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/DonKarlssonSan/pen/gROawd
```

Comment: Do you have a definition of the color range you'd like? i.e. a definition of 'purple'. And have you tried altering the colors in any way just as an experiment? Resetting the numbers in vec4 gives some interesting, if not controlled, results, so understanding that seems key.

Comment: Thanks Haworth, that is what I was looking for 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the numbers in vec4 does the trick